# Add js to module via requirejs doesn't work?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, magento2.2.2, requirejs-config.js

Does someone knows why it doesn't work ?

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/go',
        }
    }
};
console.log('foo'); // i get well "foo" in console
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/go.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function hello()
       {
           alert('hello from function');
       }    
});
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello) {
        hello();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to delete `var/view_preprocessed` and run a `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` (or deploy static assets via your workflow) as it works fine for me.

I wouldn't recommend running JS directly in a PHTML template though, the best practice is to use either `data-mage-init` or `x-magento-init` as described in the Dev Docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice but still the same problem, i deployed the static-content even im in developer mode, basically we dont need that in developer mode, and i clean the cache but nothing happen !

Comment: In your PHTML file if you add `console.log(hello);` what is the output?

Comment: Inside `require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello) { ...` I dont get it, in outside that something like this: `<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('hello');
</script>` i get it

Comment: Hmm can you add your full paths please? I don't think the issue is related to your code otherwise I would have got the same issue. I literally copied and pasted your files into `Magento_Theme` and it worked after compiling via Grunt.

Comment: Yes of course Ben, Please look my post i added them. About the compiling, i use the command ssh `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and also `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -f` because im in frensh language

Comment: I just spotted something, I've updated my answer. Did that help?

Comment: The same problem Ben, about `"module": "Magento_Theme/js/go"` according to my knowledge the `Magento_Theme` we put it when we declare the js and requirejs in the theme, however when we declare it in the module like my exemple, we need to set `Vendor_Module` instead.

Comment: Yeah you're correct, I used `Magento_Theme` as a quick way to test the code. My last idea is to remove the `console.log` from the require JS file. If that doesn't work I'm stumped as to why it works for me but not you :(

Comment: Yeaaaah, its working now :) you know what ? i cleared all this files: `var/view_preprocessed/`, `var/cache`, `pub/static`, `generated` and now it works

Comment: Just please Ben remove your updated Answer part for other people

Comment: Ah it'll be the fact you added a new file without clearing `view_preprocessed`, whenever you add a new JS or styling file you need to wipe them to re-create the symlink.

Comment: Ah okey, thank you for you and especially for your time. I added you in linkdin.

Comment: I have another problem if you want when you have time or an idea https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215704/textjs-translation-json-unnormalized2-error

Comment: please do you know how to return different functions from my `go.js` ? in my exemple i have just one function and i return it in phtml on passing the name of function hello `require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello)` how about if i want to return 10 functions ?

Comment: You should be able to return an object which contains those functions/methods. So you can call them with something like `module.functionA();` or `module.functionB();`

Comment: I just asked this question if you want to answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218896/return-all-js-functions-via-requirejs

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following layout in the requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        module: "Vendor_module/js/go",
    }
},

shim: {
    'module': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
},

deps: [
    "js/go"
]
};
```

Comment: The same issue, now when you added `deps: [
    "js/go"
]` i still have a new error : `Error: Script error for: js/go` and a warning `fail loading js/go.js`