# Return all JS functions via requirejs

Tags: magento2, requirejs, magento2.2.2, requirejs-config.js

In my exemple, i have just one function and I call it in phtml on passing the name function as param `require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello)` and it works fine.

1. Now if i want to return 10 functions for exemple, what is the best way to do that.
2. Did `deps` attribute `deps: ["js/go"]`is correct for that instead of `map`
3. I wonder if there is not a way to implemente some js libraire, ie we have to put the lib js content in a file js then we declare it in a some module then the lib content will automatically be rendered without calling all functions one by one.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/go',
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/go.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function hello()
       {
           alert('hello from function');
       }

       public function f1()
       {
           ...
       }
       public function f2()
       {
           ...
       }
       ...
});
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello) {
        hello();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/custom-javascript-in-magento-2-with-requirejs/ if you're just wanting to add a custom `.js` of local function declerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than return the function you can return an object that contains the functions, you can them call them individually whenever you need.

In this example I have 3 files:

- `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/module-a.js`
- `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/module-b.js`

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/module-b":{}
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Module A**

```
define(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($, doc) {
    'use strict';

    var moduleA = {
        functionA: function() {
            console.log('This is from module A, functionA');
        },

        functionB: function() {
            console.log('This is from module A, function B');
        }
    };

    return moduleA;
});
```

**Module B**

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'Magento_Theme/js/module-a'], function($, doc, moduleA) {
    'use strict';

    moduleA.functionA();
    moduleA.functionB();
});
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

### Alternative method

You can also do it by writing the functions outside an object, then returning only the functions you need. The positive of this method is you only return what you want to be re-usable.

Replace module A from above with this:

```
define(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($, doc) {
    'use strict';

    function functionA() {
        console.log('This is from module A, functionA. Returning an object of functions.');
    }

    function functionB() {
        console.log('This is from module A, functionB. Returning an object of functions.');
    }


    return {
        functionA: functionA,
        functionB: functionB
    }
});
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: we are obliged to here to declare two js files `module-a.js`, `module-b.js` ? why not just one js

Comment: I only added the second file to show you how to call it form another file, if you would rather add your JS inside your PHTML (I don't recommend this) then just replace your JS inside your PHTML file with module B. It works the same way in a template as it does in a second JS file.

Comment: So rather than `hello();` you would write `module.hello();`

Comment: Ok, i prefered the alternative method, but i have two question: 1. why return `{functionA, functionB}` doesn't work but `{functionA:functionA ...}` work 2. should i put moduleA as param in phtml `function($, doc){doc.functionA();}` doesn't work, `function($, doc, moduleA){moduleA.functionA();}` work I remember you that i used the alternative method

Comment: That wouldn't work because you have to give each property of your object a value, `functionA, functionB` is adding properties but not setting a value for them. Yeah you will need to add the go script as a dependency, something like `'Vendor_Module/js/go'`

Comment: Other think, when i call in a phtml a different functions it doesn't work, i have put some console.log in the last function and dont get it, but when i call just this last function, i get well the output console.log i think maybe I have some error in the other function ! have an idea how to solve this

Comment: I'd need to see your code to debug that :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74763/discussion-between-prince-and-ben-crook).

Comment: Ben please look my update, I delete it once you get the code, sorry for the length

Comment: That looks like it should work, I think you're right that another function may be breaking it.

Comment: I tested them one by one and there are many functions who breaks my log ! however when i insert them directly in phtml it works !

Comment: Ben, I found that the jqueryui does not load in my pages ! maybe it's him who's causing the issue, I added him direclty in <head></head> of my module but it gives a errors you know how to add it via require-js

Comment: Adding `'jquery/ui'` as a dependency should work

Comment: Ben, are you working with `LiveReload and Grunt` ? i have some problem with the LiveReload if yes, maybe you can answer to this post if you want of course.

Comment: Not by choice, I have one project that uses Grunt but Live Reload doesn't work with Grunt (at least for me)

Comment: Ok, thanks, the DevDocs tels that the grunt work with LiveReload `(Optional) If you want to use Grunt for "watching" changes automatically, without reloading pages in a browser each time, install the LiveReload extension in your browser. ` http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: Ben, I found the solution of `liveReload`and how to configure it with `Grunt`, if ever you need it, I've posted the complete solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219265/livereload-configuration-via-grunt/219573#219573